# how can find best docs (cars) by Google-like search query, in used car website?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm developing a web site like carmax.com or cars.com.
but this sites have many filters. I want to help user to find target car just using a search textbox like google.
I want my systems return the best cars for sale, based on search query
For example :
1- "Peugeot" > return all Peugeot car like 2008,206, ...

2- "Peugeot 206" > return all Peugeot 206

3- "Peugeot 206 at" or "Peugeot 206 auto" or "Peugeot 206 at" or "Peugeot 206 automatic" > return all automatic Peugeot 206
"Peugeot 206 at"

4- "Peugeot 206 at black 2016" or "Peugeot 206 2016 at black " , ...

can elastic search help me?
what is the best practice for this project ?

thank you

--------------------- My Edit :

{ "index": { "_id": 1 }}
{"title":"Renault,sandero,stepway,at,type 2,year 2016,white,10000 KM worked"}
{ "index": { "_id": 2 }}
{"title":"Renault,sandero,normal,manual,type 5,year 2018,black,0 KM worked "}
{ "index": { "_id": 3 }}
{"title":"Renault,kwid,normal,manual,year 2017,red,500 KM worked "}
{ "index": { "_id": 4 }}
{"title":"Peugeot,2008,normal,at,year 2019,white,0 KM worked "}


Now, i need below search query's return true Id:
1- "Renault" => return : 1,2,3
2- "Renault Sandero" or "renault sandro" or "renaultsandero" => return 1,2
3- "Renault Sandero StepWay" or "Renault stepway" or "stepway" or "step" => return 1
4- "Renault between 2016 and 2017" => return 1,3
5- "Renault more than 2017" => return 2,3

How can i config ElasticSearch ?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch can definitely help you. Just index you cars and you will be able to do this kind of search. 
Be careful with the mapping of your documents in order to have good results.